# AngularJS: what is the execution order of $watch?

Tags: angularjs

I have a watch function:

```
scope.$watch('target', function(){
   scope.hasUnsavedChanges = true;
}, true);
```

Then I change some value:

```
functiion change(target){
   scope.hasUnsavedChanges = false;
   scope.target.Xxx = '';
   console.log('scope.hasUnsavedChanges = ' + scope.hasUnsavedChanges); 
}
```

It outputs false. So when the watch function executes? 
And how to run some code after scope.hasUnsavedChanges becomes true in the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$watch` functions executes after every time `$scope.$digests()` function is called.

And if you want to execute code after a variable like `hasUnsavedChanges` become true. Wouldn't it make more sense to make it a function instead and execute all code there like:

```
scope.setUnsavedChanges = function(){  
  scope.hasUnsavedChanges = true; 
  //the rest of your code goes here
}

scope.$watch('target', function(){
   scope.setUnsavedChanges();
}, true);
```

Comment: To clarify for the OP's question, since `$watch`ers fire during digest, this is in no case immediately following a difference in results of a watched expression. In other words, it is not the changing of an object that causes the initial digest (though it does at least one following).

Comment: @Dalorzo, many thanks! But I want to run some code only for the change() function (if $watch is triggered by other functions, the code should not be executed). How to do it?

Comment: Why do you need a watcher then? If you know that you're changing the value of `target` in `change`, just execute the logic after the change is made.

Comment: `target` is changed as soon as you assign to it.  Just because it takes the $watch a little while to realize it, it doesn't mean it hasn't happened.  Right?

Comment: @Marc Kline, I want the code to run after $watch is exectued.

Comment: Yes, but why? Please update your question with more information about that request or open a new one.

Comment: @Dalorzo I think he tried to ask it in his original question. Might have accepted an answer too soon.

Comment: @MarcKline if Zach is satisfied with the answer provided how that affects you?

Comment: Did I suggest that it does? SO is about question and answers, not only subjective levels of satisfaction, I'm merely pointing out that if it's evident that their question wasn't fully answered, the OP shouldn't have accepted.